# How to configure Eclipse so it can handle a large amount of projects and code?

Tags: eclipse, memory, build-automation, out-of-memory, code-analysis

I have a lot of projects which serves me for different purposes.
I use multiple workspaces so I only import the relevant projects into each, and Eclipse's max memory is mostly within 1.2-1.6gb.

I've lately downloaded the [CodePro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-codepro) plugin, and wanted to run an schedule analysis of all the projects to see how they all comes together.

While trying it, and importing all the projects into Eclipse Indigo, and while building the workspace Eclipse turn unresponsive, and I have to terminate it from the windows "TasK Manager".

After short investigation, I've learned that this happens when Eclipse used memory reaches ~1.95gb as noticed in the Task Manager.

So what do I want to accomplish:

I would like to run a scheduled action in the CodePro plugin and analyze everything.
There is 5.2mb of code cross 178 projects.

What are my options?

Thanks in advance,
Adam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the maximum heap size that is used by Eclipse to avoid an OutOfMemoryError. See [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F) for details.

My only equivalent experience is using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer plugin to view heap dumps. I often run Eclipse with a 6GB heap and although the analysis may take some time when using this much memory it does run.